Complex groupby aggregation with cartesian product of multi-dimensional data over ManyToMany field
I have the following problem with a complex aggregation in postgres (16). The datamodel (CREATE Statements and ER-diagram) and an example of the required result set are to be found under the question.
I want to make a group-by aggregation and SUM the value column in the table datapoints. I want the sum for every given combination of the value of the year column in the table time_dimension, the value in the name column of the table spatial_dimension, and the values in the variablevar table depending on the respective related value in the name column of the table variable.
The table datapoints has a many-to-many relationship to variablevar via the bridge table datapoint_variablevalue.
variablevar and variabe are used to save statistical dimensions of a datapoint. Every datapoint thus has one value for the temporal and the spatial dimension and up to n for factual dimension, which is represented by the values in the variablevar table.
We can safely assume that every value in the table datapoint is related to exatly one value in variablevar table per value in the variable table.
(in reality a bit more complex cause very datapoint is also linked to a category...)
Basically I want the cartesian product of the temporal, spatial and factual dimensions.
Therefore I could use a cross join, and then LEFT JOIN datpoints and then GROUP BY*:
SELECT 
   COALESCE(SUM(dp.value),0),
   td.years AS years,
   sd.name AS sd_name,
   v.name AS var_name
FROM
    spatial_dimension sd
    CROSS JOIN time_dimension td
    CROSS JOIN variablevalue v
LEFT JOIN (
    datapoints dp 
    JOIN datapoint_variablevalue dv ON dp.id = dv.datapoint_id
) ON dp.time_dimension_id = td.id AND dp.spatial_dimension_id = sd.id AND dv.variablevalue_id = v.id
GROUP BY
    years,
    sd_name,
    var_name
ORDER BY 
    years DESC;

But I have two requirements:

I want SUM() to return  0 even if there is no value for a given combination

That can be done by the LEFT JOIN and COALESCE(SUM(...),0)


and I want one column per value in the variable table in the result set. Where the values in the respective columns are those from the variablevalue table, related to the variable in the variable table that the column represents.

What do I mean by the latter:
Let's assume variable had three entries in the name column: 'A','B','C'.
I want the cartesian product of

time_dimension
space_dimension
variablevar values where the related variable

is 'A'
is 'B'
is 'C'



That would result in 5 columns + the SUM column.
The result set in the above query has only one column for the variablevar values though.
The table variablevar basically saves attributes or values of a (statistical) variable, as the name already indicates. Therefore I want the result set to have one column per variable.
data model
-- all indices ommited 
CREATE TABLE time_dimension (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    years INT
     -- other fields
);
CREATE TABLE spatial_dimension (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
     -- other fields
);

CREATE TABLE variable (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    -- other fields
);

CREATE TABLE variablevalue (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    variable_id INTEGER REFERENCES variable(id)
    -- other fields
);

CREATE TABLE datapoints (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    value INTEGER, 
    time_dimension_id INTEGER REFERENCES time_dimension(id),
    spatial_dimension_id INTEGER REFERENCES spatial_dimension(id)
);

CREATE TABLE datapoint_variablevalue (
    datapoint_id INTEGER REFERENCES datapoints(id),
    variablevalue_id INTEGER REFERENCES variablevalue(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (datapoint_id, variablevalue_id)
);


data model
reproducible example
correct example result structure



space
year
variable0
variablei
variablen
sum




year
name
value
value
value
0


year
name
value
value
value
44



sqlfiddle
Here is a sqlfiddle with example data 
test data
INSERT INTO time_dimension (years) VALUES
(2019), (2020);

INSERT INTO spatial_dimension (name) VALUES
('Belgium'), ('Netherlands');

INSERT INTO variable (name) VALUES
('booktype'), ('publishing_language'), ('genre');

INSERT INTO variablevalue (name, variable_id) VALUES
('hardcover', 1),
('paperback', 1),
('FR', 2),
('NL', 2),
('prose', 3),
('poetry', 3);

INSERT INTO datapoints (value, time_dimension_id, spatial_dimension_id) VALUES 
(182, 1, 1),
(57, 1, 2),
(127, 2, 1),
(202, 2, 2);

INSERT INTO datapoint_variablevalue (datapoint_id, variablevalue_id) VALUES
(1, 2), -- paperback
(1, 3), -- FR
(1, 6), -- poetry
(2, 2), -- paperback
(2, 3), -- FR
(2, 6), -- poetry
(3, 2), -- paperback
(3, 4), -- NL
(3, 6), -- poetry
(4, 2), -- paperback
(4, 3), -- FR
(4, 5); -- prose

required result
And the result set I want:



Country
Year
BookType
Language
Genre
sum




Belgium
2019
hardcover
FR
prose
0


Belgium
2019
hardcover
FR
poetry
0


Belgium
2019
hardcover
NL
prose
0


Belgium
2019
hardcover
NL
poetry
0


Belgium
2019
paperback
FR
prose
0


Belgium
2019
paperback
FR
poetry
182


Belgium
2019
paperback
NL
prose
0


Belgium
2019
paperback
NL
poetry
0


Belgium
2020
hardcover
FR
prose
0


Belgium
2020
hardcover
FR
poetry
0


Belgium
2020
hardcover
NL
prose
0


Belgium
2020
hardcover
NL
poetry
0


Belgium
2020
paperback
FR
prose
0


Belgium
2020
paperback
FR
poetry
0


Belgium
2020
paperback
NL
prose
0


Belgium
2020
paperback
NL
poetry
127


Netherlands
2019
hardcover
FR
prose
0


Netherlands
2019
hardcover
FR
poetry
0


Netherlands
2019
hardcover
NL
prose
0


Netherlands
2019
hardcover
NL
poetry
0


Netherlands
2019
paperback
FR
prose
0


Netherlands
2019
paperback
FR
poetry
57


Netherlands
2019
paperback
NL
prose
0


Netherlands
2019
paperback
NL
poetry
0


Netherlands
2020
hardcover
FR
prose
0


Netherlands
2020
hardcover
FR
poetry
0


Netherlands
2020
hardcover
NL
prose
0


Netherlands
2020
hardcover
NL
poetry
0


Netherlands
2020
paperback
FR
prose
202


Netherlands
2020
paperback
FR
poetry
0


Netherlands
2020
paperback
NL
prose
0


Netherlands
2020
paperback
NL
poetry
0



To achieve that I came up with the following query. The problem with this query is, that it does not have a row for every given combination of variablevar values per variable rather than only those combinations actually existing.
To get the required result set a pivot might be useful but I'am not quite sure how to approach that/ wether that woul be a reasonable approach here.
So in the end my question is wether there are other ways to get the required result, especially one, where every variable has it's own column and we get a full cartesian product of all dimensions as described above.
query
WITH variables_array AS (
SELECT 
   datapoint_id,
   ARRAY_AGG(variablevalue_id)  AS varvalues
FROM datapoint_variablevalue
GROUP BY datapoint_id
)
SELECT 
    COAlESCE(SUM(dp.value),0),
    sd.name AS sp_name,
    v.varvalues AS varvalues,
    td.years AS years
FROM 
     variables_array v
     CROSS JOIN spatial_dimension sd
     CROSS JOIN time_dimension td
LEFT JOIN 
    datapoints dp
    ON  dp.id = v.datapoint_id AND dp.spatial_dimension_id = sd.id AND dp.time_dimension_id = td.id
GROUP BY 
    years,
    sp_name,
    varvalues
ORDER BY 
    years DESC;

Update
As was pointed out, pivoting will not work without knowing the columns in advance or using dynamic sql.
If the variables from the table variable, for which we want to pivot are known in advance though, one can use the query below:
In first  query the cartesian product of the temporal and spatial dimension is created, then for every targeted variable i.d 'factual dimension' another cross join is performed through a subquery filtering the variablevalue table for the specific variable. Thus a full cartesian product of spatial, temporal and all n targeted facutal dimensions is created. There is also an Array of the ids of all variablevalues per row created, which will be used in the next step.
In the next query the data for all datapoints + the data from the bridge-table datapoint_variablevalue is pulled from the database and an array of the variablevalue ids per datapoint is created.
In the last step the second query is left joined with the result set of the first query based on wether the two Arrays are identical and wether temporal and spatial dimension line up.
Perhaps someone knows how to do the pivoting with crosstab or the MAX CASE trick? I tried both but this seems to be especially complicated given, that the variables do not have to have the same amount of values.
WITH cartesian_product as (
SELECT 
    sd.name AS sd_name,
    bt.name AS book_type,
    pl.name AS publishing_language,
    gr.name AS genre,
    td.years AS years,
    ARRAY[bt.id,pl.id,gr.id] AS id_arr
FROM 
    spatial_dimension sd
    CROSS JOIN time_dimension td
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT vv.name,vv.id FROM variablevalue vv
        JOIN variable var ON vv.variable_id = var.id
        WHERE var.name= 'booktype') bt
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT vv.name,vv.id FROM variablevalue vv 
        JOIN variable var ON vv.variable_id = var.id
        WHERE var.name= 'publishing_language') pl
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT vv.name,vv.id FROM variablevalue vv
        JOIN variable var ON vv.variable_id = var.id
        WHERE var.name= 'genre') gr
GROUP BY 
    sd_name,
    book_type,
    publishing_language,
    genre,
    years,
    id_arr
ORDER BY 
    years DESC
)
SELECT 
COALESCE(SUM(dpoints.value), 0) AS sum,
cp.sd_name,
cp.years,
cp.book_type,
cp.publishing_language,
cp.genre
FROM cartesian_product cp
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT 
    dv.datapoint_id,
    dp.value AS value,
    dp.id AS dp_id,
    sd.name AS sd_name,
    td.years AS years,
    ARRAY_AGG(distinct dv.variablevalue_id) AS var_ids
FROM datapoint_variablevalue dv 
   LEFT JOIN datapoints dp ON dv.datapoint_id = dp.id
   LEFT JOIN time_dimension td ON dp.time_dimension_id = td.id
   LEFT JOIN spatial_dimension sd ON dp.spatial_dimension_id = sd.id
GROUP BY 
   dv.datapoint_id,
   value,
   dp_id,
   sd_name,
   years) dpoints
ON cp.sd_name = dpoints.sd_name
AND cp.years = dpoints.years
AND cp.id_arr::bigint[] = dpoints.var_ids::bigint[]
GROUP BY 
--the group by and the sum clause can be ommitted, if all existing variables are pivoted, but it can be still useful, in case that requirement is violated, that every datapoint ought to have only one relation to variablevalue per variable.
   cp.sd_name,
   cp.years,
   cp.book_type,
   cp.publishing_language,
   cp.genre
;


Hi - please update your question with sample data for your tables and the result you want to achieve, based on that data

Hi, I added a jsfiddle with sample data and I added a table with the results based on that sample data, that I have generated with a python script.

I’m confused. Your required result and the SQL you’ve provided don’t align (and the SQL doesn’t appear to be valid; var.name is neither a table or column you’ve included in the rest of your SQL). Also, what’s in the dbfiddle doesn’t seem to tie up with your SQL in anyway. FYI dbfiddles can be useful as an addition to the information in your question, and not as an alternative to including information in your question - so please update your question with the source data for your tables

The first word in [mre] is important

Sorry, I made indeed some typos when I translated the table names into english. I reread the table names and the queries and tested both corrected queries , that are included in the question on wether they work, they do. The second one results in the same data as the result dataset I included in the question (with the caveat mentioned in the question).

All models and queries in the question and the sqlfiddle are now identical. I only ommited the sample data in the question because of it's length. It wasn't possible to make a smaller sample data, that still would have been useful.
I have also reread the text of the question and tried to make it more clear what result I try to achieve and what is my intention.

Your tables don't have any indexes?

This post is asking two questions: how to get the desired results, and how to get those results efficiently. A smaller data set would most certainly be useful for answering the first of those two questions. A large data set might be required to address the second problem; however, in that case it might be better to generate example data using generate_series, random, and other tools. You say the query is slow, but you haven't provided any timing information (preferably as the output from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE,BUFFERS,VERBOSE)). When I ran your fiddle, the query returned quickly.

Pivoting rows into columns, when you don't know the names of those columns in advance (as they are based on row values) requires "dynamic sql". You may be better off pivoting each category individually and joining those pivots to the cartesian product. i.e. the hardest pert (imho) is achieving the multiple pivots.
